# Лаги анимации Java

Tags: java, swing, анимация

Все ссылки [здесь](http://pastebin.com/kdMxWy4z)!!!

Здравствуйте, у меня появилось желание сделать анимированную шторку с постепенным возрастанием прозрачности, но на выходе получается вот это. (Смотрите первую ссылку)

Код анимации (Смотрите вторую ссылку)

```
public void update(Graphics g) {
        //g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        //g.fillRect(startX,startY,endX-startX,endY - startY);
        if (/*Позиция мышки*/ MyMouseAdapter.keyPress && posY > startY)
            if (speed == 0)
                speed = defaultSpeed;
            else if (!MyMouseAdapter.keyPress) {
                speed -= everyTick;
                posY += speed;
            } else if (posY <= endY) {
                speed += everyTick;
                posY -= speed;
            }
        draw(g);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) { 
        int everyTick = 0;
        int thisalpha = 255;
        if (endY != posY)
            if ((endY - posY) <= 256) {
                everyTick = (int) 256 / (endY - posY);
            } else {
                everyTick = 1;
            }
        for (int y = endY; y > posY; y--) {
            if (thisalpha > 0) drawLine(thisalpha, y, g);
            else thisalpha = 0;
            if (thisalpha != 0) thisalpha = thisalpha - everyTick;
        }

    }

    void drawLine(int alpha, int y, Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(new Color(mainColor.getRed(), mainColor.getGreen(), mainColor.getBlue(), alpha)); 
        g.drawLine(startX, y, endX, y); 
    }
```

Код элемента Swing (Смотрите третью ссылку)

```
public class PaintPanel extends JPanel {
    Down down;
    public PaintPanel(){
        super();
        down = new Down(100,100,500,300);
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        down.update(g);
    }

}
```

Также в отдельном потоке идет обновление всей страницы. (Смотрите 4 ссылку)

```
public SwingFrame() {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("RMLauncher");
        jFrame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        PaintPanel paintPanel = new PaintPanel();
        jFrame.add(paintPanel);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);

        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 / FPS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            jFrame.update(jFrame.getGraphics());
        }
    }
```

Хотелось бы избавиться от рывков анимации и понять где я накосячил. Для меня работа с графиков в яве впервые, поэтому многие очевидные вещи могу не знать.

[Всё на GitHub](https://github.com/LionZXY/Launcher/tree/master/src/ru/lionzxy/launcher)

Comment: Вы сами учитесь делать анимацию? или по какому-то туториалу?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ сам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете не верный подход. Вам необходимо либо почитать про создание анимации в swing либо разобрать какой-то туториал, например вот http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Timerbasedanimation.htm